# Cannot find module 'xlsx'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, sheetjs

Am getting this while making build using jenkins on build server but i am trying this on local machine then it working fine with error

```
15:07:39 "",
15:07:39 "",
15:07:39 "ERROR in src/services/excel.service.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'xlsx'.",
15:07:39 "",
15:07:39 "2 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';",
15:07:39 " ~~~~~~"
15:07:39
```

install xlsx using
npm install xlsx

And import xlsx module.
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }
  wopts: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' };
  exportAsExcelFile(json: any, fileName:any): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    // const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.data);
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you import your service in app.module.ts and add it in the providers too?

Comment: yes its working fine in local build but not on  build server

Comment: Could you provide your app.module.ts?

Comment: `install xlsx using npm install xlsx` - did you save your module? `npm install xlsx --save`

Comment: npm install xlsx using this ...

Comment: @yazan why you need and what you want to know in app.module.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import xlsx from 'xlsx/xlsx';`

This line works for me on node/typescript environment.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the error by this line:

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx/xlsx";
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message.  I was running xlsx 18.5, so I removed it  and reloaded 17.1 and everything works fine now with a standard

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
```

No particular reason for 17.1 except it was working fine in another app and I wanted to remove that as a possibility.